# Action_Call permission not granted in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-phone-call

I am trying to make an app which can directly call if the number is entered but the permission is not granted and hence no call is made...

I have requested permission in AndriodManifest.xml

Everytime I enter a number, "Hello" pops up which is written if Granted is Not Granted.
My code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.block9;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void redirectmessage(View v) {
        String number = (((EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobnumber)).getText()).toString();
        String message = (((EditText) findViewById(R.id.textmessage)).getText()).toString();
        Uri num = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, num);
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
        startActivity(smsIntent);
    }

    public void redirectcall(View v) {
        String number = (((EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobnumber)).getText()).toString();
        Toast t = null;
        //t.makeText(getApplicationContext(),number,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            t.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.block9">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any Help would be Appreciated!!`enter code here.

Answer (score 0):

If your Target Device `API is <22` then you don't need to ask for permission as the permission will automatically provide But as a Developer you have to ready for every possibility. in case if target device `API is >=23` then you have to manually request the permission. For more information on this Read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)

```
public void redirectcall(View v) {
            String number = (((EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobnumber)).getText()).toString();
            Toast t = null;
            //t.makeText(getApplicationContext(),number,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                t.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                grantPermission();

                return;
            }
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }

    private void grantPermission() {

          // show your dialog box to ask for permission
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Call Permission Required")
                    .setMessage("This App needs Call permission, to function properly")
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //here permission will be given
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 3); // 3 is requestCode and can be any number
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();
    }
```

**After Making a Request Now, we will call @Override method `onRequestPermissionsResult()` to handle the scenario of Rejected or accepted Request**

```
*@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode){
            case 3: //remember that 3 is the same number which we specified while requesting
            {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // Call-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        redirectcall();
                    }


                }else{
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        }
    }*
```

Full MainActivity.java code is here: https://gist.github.com/Shoaibpython/eda5394ee4bc441396d68d5ef603cd3

Please consider replying here if you saw any error.

Comment: calling worked after adding, granting permission function to my code

Comment: It worked after adding `grantPermission()` to my code but I did not get the significance of `onRequestPermissionsResult()` and also it gave error cause it call redirectcall() which needed an argument.